# How to declare file-path in Javascript for object mapping?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a personal react project for learning and considering to mapping data from a JavaScript object file (not JSON in this case). There are many ways to do it. This method of works for me
 `import product1 from "../../assets/images/products/product1.jpeg";`
`<img src={ product1 } alt="item_image" />`
But I want to do it differently. I want retrieve data from a JavaScript object file (not JSON) using mapping. My `data.js` file contains data like this-

```
const data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "Meat",
        price: €2.5,
        category: "Grocery",
        path: "../../assets/images/products/product1.jpeg",
    },    
    {
        id: 2,
        title: "Milk",
        price: €1.25,
        category: "Drink",
        path: "../../assets/images/products/product2.jpeg",
    }
]

export function getData () {
    return data;
}
```

and mapping data in this way

```
import { getData } from "./data";
function Product () {

    const product = getData();

    return (
        <>
            {   
                product.map((item) => (
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <div>
                                    <span> { item.title } </span>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <span> { item.price } </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <img src={ item.path } alt="item-img" />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <div>
                                    <span> { item.category } </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ))
            }
        </>
    );
}

export default Product;
```

But I failed to get the image from this. After looking on internet, I tried to declare the `path` property using this method  `path: "file:///home/user/Documents/testapp/src/assets/images/products/product1.jpeg"`
Unfortunately this method also failed to get the product image. I am expecting a better solution from the community. --Thanks.

Comment: You need to use <img src={require('/images/image-name.png')} />

Comment: I want to get the file-path from the js object file with the ``path`` property in order to map the array objects.